# Is it possible to show a link in Django to admins only?

Tags: python, django

is it possible to test in Django if the logged in user is an admin? And just in this case to show a link normal users can't see?

Thanks
Croghs

Answer (score 2):

There's a builtin method for that. (Depending on what you call an admin though)

**[user.is_superuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser)** ?

You may even want `user.is_staff`, again, depending on what you call an admin.

Comment: `is_staff` is better — you don’t have to be a superuser to view the admin.

Comment: `is_staff` and `is_superuser` are fields/attributes, not methods. You don't need to call them.

Comment: @knbk yeah, that was a typo-ish kinda thing, typing an answer fast. thanks for the catch.